# Cannot access CiviCRM Dashboard - TypeError thrown Argument 2 passed to CRM_Core_Resources

Tags: error

Tried logging in and accessing CiviCRM Dashboard of the organisation I work for this evening (to retreive some event participant contact details) however as soon as I try to log in to CiviCRM or try to access CiviCRM Dashboard I get the following error.

NOTE: I do not have any web developer skills LOL... I am just an employee, but quite urgently need to be able to access these participant details prior to our event!

Have never had this happen before, so please excuse my noobness if this is something that is easily fixed!

Thanks in advance :)

```
Argument 2 passed to CRM_Core_Resources::addVars() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/touchingbase/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.recentmenu/recentmenu.php on line 114'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SE CiviCRM. The issue you were facing was a known error of [recentmenu extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/recent-items-menu) and was [fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.recentmenu/pull/11) and merged 6 hours ago.

You can either apply the [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/org.civicrm.recentmenu/pull/11.patch) or replace the recentmenu-1.4 extension with [recentmenu-1.5](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.recentmenu/archive/refs/tags/1.5.zip)

Comment: or disable the extension perhaps